# How can I put middle dot character inside .join()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I put middle dot character inside .join() for split arrays?

I should put this

```
<span>&#183;</span>
```

inside

```
{product.user.map(ul => ul.names).join(" ")}
```

Comment: And what is preventing you from doing this? Your question is not clear...

Comment: I want to split users names with middle dot character

Comment: `join("\u00B7")` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If I get the questions correctly, you just need to use dot instead of empty quotation marks.
A Sample modified from w3schools.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  x.innerHTML = fruits.join('.');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to join the array elements into a string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, this should work:

```
<h1>{product.user.map(ul => ul.names).join(' <span>&#183;</span> ')} </h1>
```